# React JS maintain array inside state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have been using React state to maintain some data. For ints and strings it's working well, but unfortunately arrays are not working.

In my component constructor, I have

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        terms: 5,
        myArray: []
    }
```

and then, I am trying to maintain it in componentDidUpdate

```
componentDidUpdate() {
    this.state = {
        terms: this.state.terms,
        myArray: this.state.myArray
    }
```

but `myArray: this.state.myArray` is not working. However `terms: this.state.terms` is working perfectly.

Can someone help!

Comment: why do you want to setState in componentDidUpdate method ?? and one more thing what do you mean by not working, r u trying to update the array ?

Comment: and also you should use this.setState() to update state

Comment: After rendering components, I have to change other state values.

Comment: @ Mayank Shukla Actually, I am re initialising state due to some reason, Anyhow never mind. I resolved my problem. But thank you for your timely reply. I really appreciate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Issue is you are updating the `state` value in a wrong way, Update the state value like this:

```
this.setState({
     terms: this.state.terms,
     myArray : this.state.myArray
});
```

As per [DOC](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#state):

> Never mutate this.state directly, as calling setState() afterwards may
>   replace the mutation you made. Treat this.state as if it were
>   immutable.

Update the `state array` like this, first create a copy of that by using `slice()`, then do the change and use `setState` to update:

```
let arr = this.state.myarr.slice();
arr.push('data');
this.setState({arr});
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot set state directly like that since its an array you will have to append the value or else push the value.

try something like

```
var newArray = this.state.myArray.slice();    
newArray.push("new value");   
this.setState({myArray:newArray})
```

here i sliced to make it immutable.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `this.state` with purpose to update state, you have to use:

```
this.setState(newStateObject);
```